# Google+ one-time authorization code for iOS

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-api

According to Google one-time authorization code flow is the most secure way for using Google Plus API in multiclient applications, On Google Developers site there are tutorials to implement this on Android and PHP (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth) but not in iOS.

Does anyone have successfully implemented one-time authorization code flow in iOS ?

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any success ??

Answer (score 0):

I have currently use following URL for integration google+ login and post data on google+

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: There is no information about one-time authorization in iOS

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google's document about verifying client-side tokens on the server](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/token-verification), you cannot use one-time-code flow when authenticating on an iOS app:

> The following are common situations where you might send tokens to your server:
>
> - Sending ID tokens with requests that need to be authenticated. The ID tokens tell you the particular user making the request and for which client that ID token was granted.
> - Sending ID tokens that contain OpenID 2.0 identifiers (openid_id) that need to be mapped to the Google+ ID (sub).
> - Sending client-side access tokens to the server so that the server can make requests to the Google APIs and when the one-time-code flow is not available. **For example, if your iOS app has a back-end server that needs to request data from the APIs and then background process it on behalf of the client**.